# Laravel 5.4: hasFile() no longer works

Tags: laravel, file-upload

This was working perfectly under Laravel 5.3.

I just upgraded to 5.4 and can no longer upload files using the `hasFile()` method. The check is ignored

```
public function addPhotos(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request) here shows a file in the files:FileBag

    if ($request->hasFile('photo'))
    {
        // dd($request) here never prints,
        this block is passed over as if the file doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

---

### Update

When die dumping the file, here's what I get, so you can see that something is uploading...

```
dd($request->file('photo'));
```

returns...

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#504 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "test.jpg"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -size: 0
    -error: 1
    #hashName: null
    path: ""
    filename: ""
    basename: ""
    pathname: ""
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/Users/tim/Sites/myapp/public"
    aTime: 1969-12-31 19:00:00
    mTime: 1969-12-31 19:00:00
    cTime: 1969-12-31 19:00:00
    inode: false
    size: false
    perms: 00
    owner: false
    group: false
    type: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the namespace of Request?

Comment: @alaric `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Hmm, should still exist as I'm sure you've seen.  It has been moved to a trait in 5.4 but the function's signature and implementation is identical.  I suppose you'd be receiving a fatal error if the method didn't exist anyway.  Have you tried temporarily editing the vendor source to determine what's occurring within the trait's method?  For reference, you'd be looking for https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was testing with an invalid jpeg (how is that even a thing?) so I had to create a method that would handle that scenario.

Plus, my input key is an array which will allow one or many files, so I had to handle that too...

```
public function uploadIsValid($request)
{
    foreach ($request->file('photo') as $file) {
        if (!$file->isValid()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then in my `addPhotos()` method

```
if ($this->uploadIsValid($request)) {
    // process uploaded files here...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use following method rather $request->hasFile

```
$image = $request->file('picture');
if ($image->isValid()) //return true if the file has been uploaded with HTTP and no error occurred
{ 
$imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();//assign name of image with time prefix and image extension
$destinationPath = public_path('/images');//assign destination path in public folder
$image->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
  $user->image=$imageName;
  if($user->save())
  {
   return Response::json(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Image updated','imageName'=>$imageName]);
   }
   else
   {
    return Response::json(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Image not updated']);
    }
}
```

Comment: returns `null`.

Comment: please enable 'files'=>'true' in laravel form model

Comment: It is. As I said in my post, this was working under Laravel 5.3; I was able to upload 1 - or many - files before upgrading to 5.4.

Comment: This wasn't the answer but did point me in the right direction. +1.

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests its still there. Are you sure you are doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
use Illuminate\http\UploadedFile;
```